# Error when adding new ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: visual-studio-2015

After the Update 2 of Visual Studio 2015 I get the below error every time I try to create a new ASP.NET web application project:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationInsights.Interfaces,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: When in the process of creation does that appear: before, after, or somewhere in the middle of the ASP.NET project wizard?

Comment: At the end of the process: after you choose the project type.

Comment: I have the same issue with 2015 Update 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed by choosing the Repair option of Visual Studio from Control Panel.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue for me. Any ideas what was broken?

Comment: In Windows 7 -> Start -> control panel -> programs and features -> scroll to VS2015 -> select change -> select repair